# for-each is passing all the files at once in azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory, parallel.foreach

I am a newbie in Azure and I am running into a problem with for-each activity.

Scenario: Everyday 6 files must get copied from blob storage into Azure SQL.

Day 1: Vendors-01, Transactions01, Orders01, Customers01, purchases01, history01
Day 2: Vendors-02, Transactions02, Orders02, Customers02, purchases02, history02
...

Problem: My for-each is passing all files at once multiple times instead of looping through them and passing each at a time.

in an ideal world, it should be like this

1. 1st-loop: Vendors-files
2. 2nd-loop: Transactions-files
3. 3rd-loop: Orders-files
4. 4th-loop: Customers-files
5. 5th-loop: Purchases-files
6. 6th-loop: History-files

What is happening currently:

1. 1st-loop: Vendors-files, Transactions-files, Orders-files, Customers-files, Purchases-files, History-files
2. 2nd-loop: Vendors-files, Transactions-files, Orders-files, Customers-files, Purchases-files, History-files
   ...

That's causing the pipeline to fail because the for-each is not working properly.

The Parent Pipeline

[image: the parent pipline]

Here is the count of the actual files 6, that's why the pipeline gets executed 6 times

[image]

Here is the count of each loop of the pipeline, it gives me 24 files instead of 3 similar files, or 1 at a time

[image]

Where am I missing a step?

Any feedback will be highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems there is something wrong in your `Get File List` activity. For example, in your first loop, you only want to get all  Vendors-files, but you got 24 files in the output of  `Get File List` activity which leads to you loop 24 times in `For Each File` activity. Right?

Comment: @SteveZhao yes that is correct, my Get file list is passing 24 files instead of 3 files. Like do I have to organize the similar files in one folder or?

Comment: What do you do inside `For Each File` activity, just use Copy activity? And the prefix of your filename is the same as the sample your provided?

Comment: @SteveZhao Inside my for each there will be a copy activity copying each of the 24th files from blob into Azure SQL. Files naming convention will be something like this inside blob storage.  
"Order_Number_items_29012021.txt", "Order_Number_items_30012021.txt", "Customers_Database_29012021.txt", "Customers_Database_30012021.txt"..
these are some of the files in the blob, and the files grow daily

Comment: Hi @Maryam Al-Mansour, now you have 6 types of files and perhaps 6 tables in Azure SQL. In your parent pipeline, you want to traverse 6 SQL tables. In your child pipeline, do you want to copy one file into the corresponding table  in a loop? If so, where is the digit 3 come? `Here is the count of each loop of the pipeline, it gives me 24 files instead of 3 similar files, or 1 at a time`

Comment: @JosephXu That is correct. I have 6 Azure SQL tables that I want these files to get copied to them. Essentially I have 6 files variety which are Vendors, Transactions, Orders, Customers, purchases, history. Every day I get a dump with the same file, so they will accumulate. The for each should run 6 times at each time, one categorization of the files should get copied. I said 3 similar files, meaning for example 3 vendors for 3 days should be in one loop, does that clarify the problem a bit?

Comment: Yes, I thought the timestamp would filter out only one file.  Can you show us the input of the for each activity?

Comment: @JosephXu for each will have this `@activity('Get File List').output.childItems` in its items along with sequential checked. inside the for activity, there will be a copy activity from blob to SQL table that takes `@item().name` as a filename, and at the sink, I'll be using a dynamic stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this: use wildcard paths to copy files from Blob Storage to corresponding table in Azure SQL.

my test：

1. create a variable which type is array and value are your table name.
   [image]

2.loop this array
[image]

3.use wildcard paths to filter files name
[image]

4.pass `@item()` to dataset as sink
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the variable part of the job execution is the date which is appended at the end of file and not the file names , you can achieve the result by various approaches:

1. create a config table of Dates and their processed status.

Foreach loop activity :  the value for it should be the number of extractdates that we need to process  (meaning the dates for which we need to copy the files)

within the foreach, create 6 copy activities (one for each file name like history ,order etc) where the source dataset needs to be dynamic to fetch files @cancat("order_number",utcnow()) some what like that.

2. Rather than having 6 different copy activities within the FOreach activity,
   since ADF doesnt support foreach within foreach ; create another pipeline that would contain a variable of type Array with value as the different files names.
   In the new pipeline, create a forache loop with the variable as the input and within the foreach create a copy activity.

And in the original pipeline within the foreach activity(based on date parameter), call the new pipeline.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on that please? What do you mean by the parameter of `for each`? do you mean the `get meta data` that passes `childitems` to `For Each` so instead of `childitems` it should pass date as a parameter to the `for-each` activity?

Comment: @MaryamAl-Mansour , Just to clarify on the requirement, everyday there would be 6 files in the source locations : Vendors-01, Transactions01, Orders01, Customers01, purchases01, history01 with the corresponding date appended?

Comment: @MaryamAl-Mansour,
I have updated my answer with different scenarios.
The main varying factor is the date and there can be scenario wherein the jobs failed around weekend and on Monday, you need to execute the jobs for 3 consecutive days.
So the Foreach should be based on dates for which you need to copy the files and not on the file names :)